# VBS objFile.DateLastModified and Date Format Settings

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to do some date modify check for a file in my VBS script. But it looks like comparison operation depend on date format which set on machine where script is runnnig. I have diverse machines where Regioanal & date settings could be Russian, English US, English UK and I need to run my VBS against all machines and being able to compare date correctly.

When I'm trying to use

```
If objFile.DateLastModified = cdate("19.10.2012 11:34:06") then 
do something
Else do something else
End IF
```

It seemingly works and doing correct comparison on machine with Russian formats setting, but fails on machine with English UK formats setting with following error

```
Type mismatch: 'cdate'
800A000D
```

If I use `following DateSerial(2012,10,19)` it doesn't throw an error but fail to compare dates correctly.

What is the best and easiest way to compare file modify date against predifined value with VBS irrespectively of machine date format setting?

Comment: Relevant reading: [XKCD 1179: ISO 8601](http://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 4):

Long story short: Don't use localized date formats when parsing dates.

ISO 8601 format works just fine:

```
If objFile.DateLastModified = CDate("2012-10-19 11:34:06") Then
  ' do something
Else
  ' do something else
End If
```

If you must, you can use the [`SetLocale()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf99h19%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) explicitly to make your script run under different environments:

```
SetLocale 1049  ' LCID "Russian"
MsgBox CDate("5.4.2013 15:00:00")  ' April 5, shown as 05.04.2013 15:00:00

SetLocale 1033  ' LCID "English - United States"
MsgBox CDate("5.4.2013 15:00:00")  ' Type mismatch error
```

Refer to the [list of assigned LCIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) on the MSDN.

Comment: Code you suggesed: `If objFile.DateLastModified = CDate("2012-10-19 11:34:06") Then` Worked for me - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use

   ```
   objFile.DateLastModified = DateSerial(2012,10,19) + TimeSerial(11,34,06)
   ```
2. Use a Date literal (format `#mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM#`, locale-independent):

   ```
   objFile.DateLastModified = #10/19/2012 11:34:06 AM#
   ```
3. Use what [xkcd tells you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078043/vbs-objfile-datelastmodified-and-date-format-settings#comment22951230_16078043).

   ```
   objFile.DateLastModified = CDate("2012-10-19 11:34:06")
   ```