# VB Script to write date gives wrong format

Tags: datetime, file-io, vbscript

I have a script which reads all the files in a remote dir and sets the file object to the oldest file. It then writes that file's creation/modified date into another file.

Issue: 
It writes the date in a weird format - yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss
I want format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

```
Option Explicit  
Dim fso, path, file, recentDate, recentFile, objFileHandle
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set recentFile = Nothing
For Each file in fso.GetFolder("\\remoteServer\Drive\Folder").Files
  If (recentFile is Nothing) Then
    Set recentFile = file
  ElseIf (file.DateLastModified < recentFile.DateLastModified) Then
    Set recentFile = file
  End If
Next

Set objFileHandle = fso.OpenTextFile("\\remoteServer\Drive\Folder\oldestDateTime.Txt", 2, "True")
objFileHandle.Write(recentFile.DateLastModified)
objFileHandle.Close
```

Anybody have an idea how i can get the format i want?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatdatetime.asp)

```
objFileHandle.Write(FormatDateTime(recentFile.DateLastModified, vbShortDate))
```

Should go some way to giving you what you want.

Unless, of course, you're talking about locale-based formatting? See also this question: [VBS objFile.DateLastModified and Date Format Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078043/vbs-objfile-datelastmodified-and-date-format-settings) and its answers

Comment: No -vbShortDate will remove the time but the date format itself will remain wrong. Its to do with my server or sql servers region settings i think as if i execute the vbs on my laptop it generates the date correctly.

Comment: Which was why I added the caveat about local-based formatting and the link to the existing question. ;-)